# Stone compaction on placement

Tags: stone

Good morning,

I'm currently working on a crew installing 18" RCP storm sewer and our company is back filling the trench with uncompacted #8 stone. I've mentioned the fact that there will be future settling without compaction. What is the percentage of compaction for #8 stone on placement without compaction? Thanks for your time.

Tim

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Good question: keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, compaction is very important in order to control future settlement.

Generally, we require a minimum of 95% compaction under a “Proctor” test that governs moisture content, maximum of 6” depth lifts, etc.

Remember, compaction is not just weight...vibration is important too.

So, to answer your question, if gravel is dumped at approximately 80% compaction, then there’s a difference of about 15% settlement. (This is highly dependent on the type of gravel, manner in which the gravel is deposited, etc. )

Here is an article that explains it:
https://www.multiquip.com/multiquip/pdfs/Soil_Compaction_Handbook_low_res_0212_DataId_59525_Version_1.pdf